# Swift - Set LeftBarItem in TabNavigation

Tags: swift

I have a viewcontroll that is embedded in a tabNavigation. HomeVc.swift

I want to set the title at the top and the leftbaritem. But it is not showing up if I do this in the HomeVC.swift.

MainVC.swift (TabNavigationController)

```
let homeNC: UINavigationController = {

    let _vc = HomeVC()
    let _nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: _vc)

    _nc.title = "Home"
    _nc.tabBarItem.image = UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .home, textColor: UIColor.black, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))


    return _nc
}()

viewControllers = [homeNC]
```

---

(HomeVC.swift)

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Sign Out", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handlesSignOut))
        self.title = "Home"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        setupUI()
    }
}
```

if I place it in the MainVC.swift which is the TabNavigation controller it all works.

The idea is that when the user clicks on the tabbar item at the bottom and the view switches, each view may have its own leftbaritem.

I thought putting the code in the viewcontroller would do this.

Comment: Your HomeVC is embedded in a Navigation Controller right?

Comment: your code is assuming that the viewController has its own `navigationController`, so instead of embedding your tabBarController with the navigationController, you should do the contrary, each VC has its NVC